# Are const vector references passed as argument allocated on the heap?

Tags: c++

Considering a function:

```cpp
int f(
        const std::vector<int>& v1,
        const std::vector<int>& v2)
{
    int sum_1 = 0;
    for (int a: v1)
        sum_1 += a;
    int sum_2 = 0;
    for (int a: v2)
        sum_2 += a;
    return std::max(sum_1, sum_2);
}
```

When calling:

```cpp
f({5, 7, 9}, {1, 2, 4, 3})
```

Are these vectors allocated on the heap? If yes, what would be a better design to avoid these allocations?

Comment: When passed by reference the `vector`s, stay in whatever storage they were allocated in. They are references. They refer to an existing object.

Comment: I would suspect the compiler to detect that they are created when passed and won't be used again afterwards, and do some optimizations because of this

Comment: In `f({5, 7, 9}, {1, 2, 4, 3})` the `vector`s are temporary variables. Handy reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary

Comment: That's a reasonable expectation. [The compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants so long as there are no changes to the observable code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). In this case a smart enough compiler might be able to reduce all the way to a constant 21.

Comment: Doesn't seem like any compiler implements such optimization, all of them call `operator new` or `std::vector::vector()`: https://godbolt.org/z/61cMv8rhs

Comment: Wow. Identical to mine: https://godbolt.org/z/nq54c1ojv Or almost. I threw in a `printf` to make sure the work didn't get completely optimized out.

Comment: Here: [fully optimized](https://godbolt.org/z/TY5vTfK7c) and it only returns `21`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Good call, works with good old `constexpr` variable too https://godbolt.org/z/9znvvMMqf.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yeah - though, I had to "cheat" and use clang trunk. Clang 14 doesn't accept any of those versions.

Comment: Interesting that the compiler's smart enough to do it if you ask, but doesn't volunteer it. I wonder if that's to keep compile time down when it's not explicitly requested.

Comment: `int f(std::span<const int> v1, std::span<const int> v2) {...}` called as `f(std::array{5, 7, 9}, std::array{1, 2, 4, 3});` . Requires C++20. Doesn't do memory allocation.

Comment: The short answer is 'no', but it isn't specified or required. A compiler implementor would have to be mad to engage in `new` and `delete` (and probably `try/catch` to ensure deletion), when he could just allocate the temporaries on the stack and be done with it.

Comment: I don't see how duplicate answers this particular question. It doesn't mention classes that manage memory at all. Sure, `std::vector`s will be stored on stack, but their content is not.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It doesn't have to mention them. Classes that manage memory do whatever they do, whether they are instantiated as temporaries or not. They don't know whether they are temporaries. The salient fact is that the only implementation for temporaries that makes any sense is on the stack, and that's what it says in the duplicate.